# How to increase the thickness of the graph lines and remove the point?

Tags: pgfplots

[image]

It is necessary to remove the round and square dots on the graphs lines. And to increase the thickness of the line.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[date coordinates in = x,
    table/col sep = semicolon,
    height = 0.3\paperheight, 
    width = 0.7\paperwidth,
    xmin=2015-10-01,
    xmax=2015-12-31,
    ymin=30,
    ymax=55,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={}
]
        \addplot table[x index=0, y index=1, col sep=comma] {oil_prices.csv};
        \addplot table[x index=0, y index=2, col sep=comma] {oil_prices.csv};  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Add

```
    no markers,
    every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick}
```

to the `axis` options. I don't have your data files, so in the example below I've used random numbers. Instead of `ultra thick` you can use any of the other default styles defined by TikZ (`semithick`, `thick` and `very thick`), or set the width explicitly using e.g. `line width=4pt`. (4pt is likely too much, but adjust to your liking).

Left is default, right is `ultra thick` without markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    name=ax1,
]
        \addplot {rnd};
        \addplot {rnd};
    \end{axis}


\begin{axis}[
    at={(ax1.outer north east)},anchor=outer north west,     
    no markers,
    every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick}
]
        \addplot {rnd};
        \addplot {rnd};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```