Plot the fractional part function
To plot the fractional part function f(x)=x-floor(x), I use the following code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    ymin=-0.2, ymax=1.2, % Adjusted y-axis limits
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ytick={0,1}, % Specify the y-ticks
    xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}, % Specify the x-ticks
    domain=-3:3, % Domain for the plot
    samples=5000 % Increase samples for a smoother plot
]
% Plot fractional part function
\addplot [
    jump mark mid,
    very thick, red
] {x-floor(x)};

\node[red, above] at (axis cs: 2,1.05) {$f(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}

The problem is that the lines do not appear thick. Is there a better way to plot such discontinuous functions? Thanks a lot!
EDIT: Even when I increase the width, the quality is not better.


Surprisingly, removing jump mark mid makes the plot thicker as it is supposed to be. Also see this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312078/how-to-increase-the-thickness-of-the-graph-lines-and-remove-the-point

With jump mark mid all the lines are horizontal and when you increase the samples to something extreme like 5000 they become very short. A thick horizontal very short line appears vertical. 5000 of these placed slanted gives your thin plot.
Here is a plot that shows what happens, and a possible solution:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle]
\addplot[red, jump mark mid, domain=-3:3, samples=100, very thick] {x-floor(x)+2};
\addplot[teal, jump mark mid, domain=-3:3, samples=100] {x-floor(x)+1};
\foreach \i in {-3,...,2}
\addplot[blue, very thick, domain=\i:\i+0.99, samples=2] {x-floor(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


